# how to connect to a mysql server running on a linux virtual machine in azure

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, mysql-workbench, azure-virtual-machine

I searched a lot but not able to solve that problem.
i am able to access MySQL server running on different windows machine. steps i have taken are

1. changing my.ini file bind address to 0.0.0.0
2. creating user and granting permission by `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE.* TO user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
3. from command line to windows MySQL server `mysql -h windows server ip -u user -p`

it works fine and from MySQL workbench i am able to connect for windows MySQL server from my machine. BUT when in Linux virtual machine i have done the same thing

1. changing my.cnf file and change bind address to 0.0.0.0.
2. creating user and granting permission by `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE.* TO user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
3. From command line to LINUX MySQL server `mysql -h linux server ip -u user -p`

   but for that i am getting following error after giving password **ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'linux server ip' (10060)** also when connecting from c# by following connection string `<add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Server=LINUX_VM_SERVER_IP;Database=database;Uid=user;Pwd=password" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`
   i am getting **Error : Unable to find and specified mysql host**
4. i have checked in LINUX_VM that 0.0.0.0:3306 is in listening status.
5. if i try to telnet LINUX_VM MYSQL Server service using `/>telnet
   LINUX_VM_IP 3306` i got the **ERROR : Connecting To
   LINUX_VM_IP...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306:**

Comment: Are you trying to connect from outside Azure (e.g. your on-premises machine)? Hard to actually tell, as you don't ever specify the details - just lots of config and errors.

Comment: If you've used the default marketplace template then your Network Security Group (NSG) won't have an inbound rule on it for MySQL, so you'll need to add that rule in.

Comment: i am trying to connect from outside of azure. from my local machine MySQL workbench and also from c# Web API.  connection of database inside the virtual machine is working and tested with locally hosted app in vm. however these are the error that i tried and getting after connection outside of azure Linux VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try to connect to the database on the VM hosting the database. If the connection is successful, then the configuration of the database is correct. Otherwise, please check the configuration of your database.

Second, if you are able to connect to database on the VM, then the most possible cause of this issue is firewall. Please check if the local firewall (iptables) allows inbound connection on port 3306. For test purpose, you may disable the firewall temporarily. Also, please check if the NSG has been configured properly to allow the inbound traffic on port 3306.

Besides, if the VNET has been associated with a NSG, then we need to allow the inbound traffic in the NSG too.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, i am able to connect to database inside azure Linux VM. i will check those configuration that you told and i let you know when i am done.

Comment: ok. as you said it is possible as our team discuss but we are not using this because we decided not to disclose database out of vm, thanks.